# Update row in database + Onkeylistenner

Tags: android, sqlite, keylistener

i have a layout which contains an `EditText` , i used a `key listenner` to submit values entred in the EditText.The submission is confirmed onclick on Enter Now i want to update the value in my table after confirmation but i don't konw how.
this is my activity

```
 public class Income extends Activity {

        private EditText edittext;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.income);
            CategoriesDAO dab = new CategoriesDAO(this);
            addKeyListener();

        }



         public void addKeyListener() {

            edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1income);           
            edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)&&(edittext.length()==0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Income.this,"Set up monthly income to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;

                } else if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)&&(edittext.length()!=0)) {


                    Toast.makeText(Income.this,
                        "Monthly income is successfully modified to "+edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
     });
    }
```

I tried to do something like myobject

```
myobject = dab.getobjet;
 myobject.setedittext;
 dab.update(myobject)
```

but i couldn't do this in the function addKeyListener() , how can i get the edited text and ypdate my database directly after the edition??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make your `dab` a member of your Activity:

```
 private CategoriesDAO dab;
```

you can then access this field from inside your listener the same way you did with your editText.

Comment: can u explain me please why i couldn't use CategoriesDAO dab = new CategoriesDAO(this)?? or what does this  mean??

Comment: You had declared `dab` as a local variable inside onCreate method, so outside of onCreate `dab` didn't exist. Solution was to create a field that exists the whole lifecycle of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Put your dab as a member of your class, you will then have to possibility to access it as you need.

do not use the this keyword to access it because "this" do not represent your activity at that  moment ;)

regards